# How to evaluate Rep of new type in Isabelle?

Tags: types, code-generation, isabelle, isar

I'm trying to evaluate terms corresponding to the type `t` defined as follows.

```
typedef t = "{(0::nat)..10}" by auto
```

To evaluate terms of type `t`, I simply define `Abs_t` as a constructor.

```
lemma [code abstype]: "Abs_t (Rep_t x) = x" by (rule Rep_t_inverse)
code_datatype Abs_t
```

This allows me to use, for example,

```
value "Abs_t 4"
```

Now, I want to evaluate terms of the form `Rep_t x` such that they map back to naturals.
However, `Rep_t (Abs_t x) = x` only holds for `x` in `{(0::nat)..10}` so it cannot be used as a code equation.

I can write a single code equation for each element in the domain like so

```
lemma[code]:
 "Rep_t (Abs_t 0) = 0"
 "Rep_t (Abs_t 1) = 1"
 (* ... *)
 "Rep_t (Abs_t 10) = 10"
 by(auto simp add: Abs_t_inverse)
```

but that becomes infeasible for larger domains.

What is the proper way to define code equations such that `value "(Rep_t (Abs_t x))"` evaluates to `x::nat` for all `x` in the domain?

I tried to use the code equations

```
lemma [code abstype]: "Rep_t (Abs_t x) = x"
```

which failed for the reason explained above.
I also tried to used

```
lemma [code abstype]: "Rep_t (Abs_t x) = (if x \in {(0::nat)..10} then x else undefined)"
```

which I could not manage to proof.